# Eigen conservativeResize strange behavior

Tags: c++, matlab, reshape, eigen

I am using m.conservativeResize() to do the equivalent in Eigen as the reshape function in MatLab. So let N = 3, and then...

```
static MatrixXd m(N*N,1);
```

and then I assign this matrix some values, and it looks like this:

```
1
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
1
```

and then try to reshape it...

```
m.conservativeResize(N,N);
```

So now the same values should be there, but now in N rows and N columns rather than N*N rows and one column.

However that's not what I get. The first column has the first three values in the column vector - OK so far - but then the remaining values just look like garbage values from uninitialized memory:

```
1  3.08116e-309      0.420085
1 -2.68156e+154    1.2461e-47
0 -2.68156e+154      0.634626
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`conservativeResize()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a4ac24a195e3e35ce2d8946cee5873e51) doesn't ``move" the elements around (in other words, doesn't work like MATLABs `reshape`, since it performs memory re-allocation even if the initial and final sizes are the same). From the documentation:

> *Resizes the matrix to rows x cols while leaving old values untouched.*
>
> ...
>
> *Matrices are resized relative to the top-left element. In case values need to be appended to the matrix they will be uninitialized.*

These statements seem a bit confusing. What it means is the following: think about the initial matrix as a rectangle, of size A x B. Then think about the resized matrix as another rectangle of size C x D. Then mentally overlap the two rectangles, making sure the top-left corner is common to both. The common elements of the intersection are the ones that are preserved by the `conservativeResize`. The rest just correspond to uninitialized memory.

In case you want a true reshaping, use [`resize()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#afbbb33d14fe7fb9683019a39ce1c659d) instead (making absolutely sure that A x B == C x D, otherwise reallocation takes place and all bets are off).

Comment: Very many thanks for your answer! I used resize() and that works. Cheers!

Comment: BTW, how does resize work in Eigen? Is it computationally expensive? Or is it just a matter of changing the way the array is indexed?

Comment: @AaronSchurger It is not expensive whenever the old and new sizes are compatible (A x B == C x D). In this case, no re-allocation is made, only the view is changed. Otherwise, a reallocation takes place, without copying the elements.

Comment: I agree that the statement is confusing. I thought that it means that the original matrix coefficients would remain unchanged during the transfer to a new matrix, which is exactly the opposite from what it does.

Comment: @vsoftco If no re-allocation is made, how is resize() compared with Eigen::Map? i.e. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html

Comment: @AlanWang `resize()` doesn't do re-allocation only if `A*B == C*D`. In this case it behaves like `Map`. Otherwise `resize()` re-allocates and all elements are lost (unlike `conservativeResize()` which keeps old elements).